# pandas read_csv with chunksize but deleted raw CSV accidentally

Tags: python, pandas

So I have this long file that I've been reading in chunks:

```
dfchunks = pd.read_csv(txtfile, chunksize=100000, iterator=True)
for i, chunk in enumerate(dfchunks):
  do_something(chunk, *args, **kwargs)
```

Now this has been going on, I'm logging everytime a chunk is finished. Problem is I accidentally moved `txtfile` to another folder.

I moved the file back. The script is still running (no errors whatsoever). Is there any chance I messed it all up?

Comment: If there are no errors then it is very unlikely.  I have limited understanding of how "iterator" works in read_csv, but every time I have used it it reads in the entire file and, as you have it written, never accesses the file again.  FYI: if you want to chunk the file you should use dfchunks.get_chunk(chunk_size)

Comment: @tnknepp I hope so too. Also I did have a chunksize kwarg in `read_csv` (edited the question now). Didn't know about `get_chunk` though, thanks for that info!

Comment: It's not directly related to the question, but is the `iterator=True` necessary here? Also, are you specifying the dtype somehow, to avoid issues related to data type inference? That's probably more dangerous than accidentally moving the file.

Comment: @AMC I actually don't use iterator=True, but somehow I wrote it in the code. I have to check what it does....